# Is there a way to combine a SELECT and ALTER statement (combining DML and DDL)?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ddl

I wanted to rename an index dynamically.

Backstory: Oracle creates an index automatically on materialized views if the base table has a primary key(I think?). The name of that index changes each time the MV is dropped and created. I want to rename that index.

My plan was to select the index name then put that into the alter statement.

```
Select table_owner||'.'||INDEX_Name 
  from all_indexes
 WHERE table_name = 'mytable' 
   and table_owner = 'myuser' 
   and uniqueness = 'UNIQUE';
ALTER INDEX (that select statement here) 
  RENAME TO abetterindexname
```

But that threw this error:

```
ORA-00953: missing or invalid index name
```

I figured out my answer before posting. Here is what worked:

```
DECLARE
avariable  varchar2(100);
BEGIN
Select table_owner||'.'||INDEX_Name 
  into avariable  
  from all_indexes
 WHERE table_name = 'mytable' 
   and table_owner = 'myuser' 
   and uniqueness = 'UNIQUE';
execute immediate 'ALTER INDEX '||avariable||' RENAME TO abetterindexname';
 END;
```

Source:  https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7038453003289. -- I had to build a string for the execute immediate statement.

If anyone knows how to do this with only sql, I would be interested.

Comment: You should [edit] the question and move the answering path to an answer you then accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't do it in SQL. SQL is a query language.
You can only use a DDL like

```
ALTER INDEX <old name> RENAME TO <new name>
```

or plsql with a dynamic sql

```
begin
  execute immediate 'ALTER INDEX '||<old name>||' RENAME TO '|| <new name>;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run DDL in a pure SQL statement using the new 12c `WITH` function.

The below statement is a normal `SELECT` statement, using a common table expression.  But this common table expression references a function that runs a SQL statement.  This code does not require installing any objects and can be run in a `SELECT` context.

```
with function exec_sql(p_sql varchar2) return number is
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
    execute immediate p_sql;
    return 1;
end;
select exec_sql('ALTER INDEX '||owner||'.'||index_name||' RENAME TO abetterindexname')
from all_indexes
where table_name = 'MYTABLE'
    and table_owner = owner
    and uniqueness = 'UNIQUE';
/
```

But it is not recommended to run changes like this as part of a `SELECT` statement.  Oracle does not guarantee the exact order and number of times parts of a `SELECT` statement are executed (although in practice we can usually figure it out).  It is much safer to run the change in a PL/SQL anonymous block.  This technique is probably only useful for situations where we have limited access to the database, like a tool that only runs `SELECT` statements.